# How to force iCloud file to be synchronized?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, icloud, icloud-drive

I'm using iCloud drive to synchronize each devices of a user and it works relatively well except sometime when a file is not direclty uploaded to iCloud Drive. To unlock this situation, I have to open the "Files" folder on the device which send the file and it looks as it force synchronization because then all the other devices detect the change and it works.
A simple solution is to find **how to force iCloud files synchronization** ?

**I didn't find any clean solutions, may someone have found a hack to ask iCloud to synchronize files ?**

Thank's a lot